# Issue while applying border to a combobox with ie7

Tags: html, css

css:

```
.combobox{
    color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DB6E6E;
}
```

html:

```
<select class = "combobox">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
```

"combobox" properties are fine with all browsers except ie7 (border isn't red). I tried to add this combo to a div which i gave the class properties but nothing change.
how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adding border-style:

```
.combobox{
    color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DB6E6E;
    border-style: solid;/*must be added to make it work*/
}
```

In shorter form, you can use `border` property:

```
.combobox{
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #DB6E6E;
}
```

---

Also, in your html, don't separate the class attribute and it's value:

```
<select class = "combobox">
<!----------^^ ^^ ------use class="combobox" ----->
```

Comment: i tried what you suggested but unfortunately the problem on IE 7 is always there

Comment: your suggestion is working with implementing the combobox in a div. so your answer helped me

Comment: plus giving the class to the div